# How to set jacoco coverage percentage to 60% at child's pom?

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Can some one tell me how to set Jacoco code coverage to a certain percentage in Child's POM. I have a parent dependency which is expecting 80% coverage. I need to limit that to 60% in my child project. I am setting 0.600 under child's pom properties. But this is not overriding the parent's coverage goal which is 80%. Any comments are appreciated..

```
<jacoco.percentage.instruction>0.600</jacoco.percentage.instruction>
```

Comment: you sure this is the jacoco plugin? the docs don't mention this property at all: https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html - and the limit config looks quite different. or is this some own build property like here: https://automationrhapsody.com/automated-code-coverage-of-unit-tests-with-jacoco-and-maven/ ? you can always run your build with -X to see the plugin config or mvn help:effective-pom to figure out whats going on. worst case is add the complete plugin config into your pom

Comment: config aftr  mvn effective-pom
` <execution>
<id>default-check</id><goals>
<goal>check</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <rules>
                  <rule>
                    <limits>
                      <limit>
                        <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                        <minimum>80.0%</minimum>
                      </limit>
                    </limits>
                  </rule>
                </rules>
              </configuration>
            </execution>`

Comment: That is what I can after running mvn effecitve-pom

Comment: well, I would think that config is in some parent pom somewhere. if it is using a property make sure its the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is we cannot override just properties of Jacoco. I have copied the below parent's pom plug in to my project and I have updated the minimum covered ratio to 60% where it was 80% in parent's pom. This is working for me.

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
   <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.2</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>default-check</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <rules>
               <rule>
                  <limits>
                     <limit>
                        <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                        <minimum>60.0%</minimum>
                     </limit>
                  </limits>
               </rule>
            </rules>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
         <id>default-audit-check</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
            <rules>
               <rule>
                  <limits>
                     <limit>
                        <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                        <minimum>60.0%</minimum>
                     </limit>
                  </limits>
               </rule>
            </rules>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
         <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <propertyName>jacoco.surefire.argLine</propertyName>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```